Need unknown polar function
I'm looking to reproduce the function attached below or at least something that looks close to it. Polar coordinates. I found $r(\theta) = 1-0.5\sin^2(2\theta)$ to be somewhat close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!


Welcome to MathSE! You should start by editing into the question the motivation/context behind that plot, otherwise this will get closed and downvoted soon.

Its a function $r(\phi)= a  + b \cos (2 \phi) + c \cos(4 \phi)$
e.g.
  PolarPlot[
   4 (1 + 1/5 Cos[2 \[Phi]]) + Cos[4 \[Phi]] , {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]


The constant term is  a circle, the second $\pi$-periodic makes it ellipsoidal and the $\pi/2$-periodic deforms the radius along the diagonals.
